# Restar fechas en swift

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

Necesito restar dos fechas y obtener el número de dias que transcurren de una a otra.

Tengo este código en el que obtengo los campos de la fecha, por lo que lo puedo poner en cualquier formato:

```
let arrayFechaDesde = AppDelegate().explode(caracter: " ", cadena: fechaDesde)
let arrayFechaDesdeDos = AppDelegate().explode(caracter: " ", cadena: arrayFechaDesde[1])
let dayDesde = arrayFechaDesdeDos[0]
let monthDesde = arrayFechaDesdeDos[1]
let yearDesde = arrayFechaDesdeDos[2]

let arrayFechaHasta = AppDelegate().explode(caracter: " ", cadena: fechaHasta)
let arrayFechaHastaDos = AppDelegate().explode(caracter: " ", cadena: arrayFechaHasta[1])
let dayHasta = arrayFechaHastaDos[0]
let monthHasta = arrayFechaHastaDos[1]
let yearHasta = arrayFechaHastaDos[2]
```

La variable `fechaDesde` y `fechaHasta` tienen este formato: `11/10/2016 08:00`

Como puedo restar ambas fechas para obtener el numero de dias que han transcurrido de una a otra??

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta exactamente?

Comment: Como puedo restar dos fecha @Error404

Comment: Me refiero, ¿qué obtienes ahora? ¿qué resultado esperas? ¿qué contiene `arrayFechaDesde[1]`?

Comment: La cadena de entrada es: `11/10/2016 08:00` y en el array guardo en 0, 1 y 2 - dia, mes y año respectivamente @Error404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para restar ambas fechas no es necesario que separes en un arreglo dia, mes, año.

En `swift` tienes el objeto de tipo `NSCalendar` que básicamente en su documentación dice :

[NSCalendar Documentación en Ingles](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendar)

> NSCalendar son objetos que encapsulan información sobre calculos de tiempo...

Creamos un objeto `NSCalendar`

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
```

Luego creamos

```
let fecha_desde = calendar.startOfDayForDate(fechaDesde)
let fecha_hasta = calendar.startOfDayForDate(fechaHasta)
```

Este metodo `startOfDayForDate` devuelve la fecha e ignora la hora que tu fecha tiene. *¿Por que hacemos esto?* Porque si quieres saber exactamente la diferencia en dias entre dos fechas debes ignorar las horas porque esto puede devolverte 0 en caso que no hayan transcurrido 24 horas entre una fecha y otra.

Luego

```
let dias= NSCalendarUnit.Day
```

Creamos una variable del tipo `NSCalendarUnit.Day` que especifica unidades de calendario en este caso como queremos dias, le decimos `Day`

```
let result = calendar.components(dias, fromDate: fecha_desde , toDate: fecha_hasta, options: [])
```

La funcion `calendar.components` nos permite calcular la diferencia entre una fecha y otra y en la unidad que queramos, en este caso `dias`

Y finalmente obtenemos

```
result.day
```

Que es la diferencia entre las dos fechas en `dias`

**EDIT**

Swift 3 al parecer no trabaja con `NSCalendar` en su lugar ocupa `Calendar`

[dataComponents swift](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/calendar/2293176-datecomponents)

En su lugar para swift 3 :

```
let dias= Set<Calendar.Component>([.day])
let result = calendar.dateComponents(dias, from: fechaDesde as   Date,  to: fechaHasta as Date)
result.day
```

Comment: esta funcion: `let result = calendar.components(dias, fromDate: fecha_desde , toDate: fecha_hasta, options: [])` en `swift 3` da error

Comment: que error exactamente @AlbertoMier

Comment: `Argument labels '(_:, fromDate:, toDate:, options:)' do not match any available overloads`

Comment: Actualizado! @AlbertoMier

Comment: Ya funciona. Gracias